# Jenkins GitLab Community Edition Integration Error

Tags: jenkins, gitlab, webhooks, cicd

I'm trying to integrate `Jenkins` (ver. 2.337) for our project on our `gitlab.doman.com` (GitLab Community Version  13.0.3), and it is deployed and running on `Linux Centos` on `AWS EC2`.
When I try to test using my GitLab `Access Token`, it gives me error stating `Connection Timed Out`.
When I try with Gitlab webhooks and SSH Key as credentials instead of Access Token, webhooks execute successfully, but the job on jenkins fails with the below errors.

I am quite new to Jenkins, and CI/CD. So, any guidance or help resolving this issue is greatly appreciated!

Jenkins Console Log:

```
Started by GitLab push by j****
Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/xx_xxxxx
The recommended git tool is: NONE
using credential 7c284997-927a-40d9-b1cf-02axxxxxxxxx
 > /usr/bin/git rev-parse --resolve-git-dir /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/xx_xxxxx/.git # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > /usr/bin/git config remote.origin.url git@gitlab.sampledomain.co.kr:xx_xxxxxDetection/xx_xxxxx_detection.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from git@gitlab.sampledomain.co.kr:xx_xxxxxDetection/xx_xxxxx_detection.git
 > /usr/bin/git --version # timeout=10
 > git --version # 'git version 1.8.3.1'
using GIT_SSH to set credentials GitLab_SSH_Key
 > /usr/bin/git fetch --tags --progress git@gitlab.sampledomain.co.kr:xx_xxxxxDetection/xx_xxxxx_detection.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10

ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to fetch from git@gitlab.sampledomain.co.kr:xx_xxxxxDetection/xx_xxxxx_detection.git
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:1001)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1242)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1302)
    at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:540)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1215)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:645)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:85)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:517)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1896)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:44)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:101)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:442)
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "/usr/bin/git fetch --tags --progress git@gitlab.sampledomain.co.kr:xx_xxxxxDetection/xx_xxxxx_detection.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: ssh: connect to host gitlab.sampledomain.co.kr port 22: Connection timed out
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2671)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2096)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$500(CliGitAPIImpl.java:84)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:618)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:999)
    ... 11 more
ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [GitLab Access Token](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/personal_access_tokens.html) would work only for HTTPS URL (replacing your GitLab account password)

If you see `Connection timed out` *both* for HTTPS URL and SSH URL (`git@gitlab.sampledomain.co.kr:...` as in your question), it means `gitlab.sampledomain.co.kr` is not reachable from the Jenkins controller server which tries to contact your Git repository hosting server.

You need to make sure such a server can do a simple `curl -v telnet://gitlab.sampledomain.co.kr:22` or `curl -v telnet://gitlab.sampledomain.co.kr:443`, before being able to run a service like Jenkins.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
I tried them both, and I think it is reachable.
Here is the screenshot:
[![telnet-success.png](https://i.postimg.cc/gj3RF8MR/telnet-success.png)](https://postimg.cc/n9cMqjfc)


Anything else I should check?

Comment: @JumanazarSaidov Is this done from the same server the Jenkins is running on?

Comment: No. Jenkins is running on AWS EC2, and I ran them on my local.

Comment: @JumanazarSaidov Exactly: that is my point. You see those errors with Jenkins. Meaning, Jenkins, running on its AWS EC2 server, is not able to contact your GitLab server.

Comment: Sorry. You were right!
My Gitlab is not reachable from my EC2 server.

[![telnet-failed.png](https://i.postimg.cc/QCMtS72h/telnet-failed.png)](https://postimg.cc/G8Zdm435)

Can you suggest anything to fix it?

Comment: @JumanazarSaidov Not sure, after reading https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/-/issues/4524. Maybe having your own GitLab on your AWS EC2 instance? (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/install/aws/#patterns-for-using-gitlab-with-aws)